# Vertical alignment of inline labels in pgfgantt

Tags: labels, pgfgantt

It seems that `pgfgantt` is vertically aligning `inline` label by automatically taking into account the space for descenders:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    inline,
]{1}{4}
\ganttbar{XX}{2}{3}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image] [image]

The same can also be seen in the examples in the `pgfgantt`'s manual. How can I force it to vertically center labels if there are no descenders?
I achieved this by setting `bar inline label node/.append style={text depth=.5ex}`, but I don't want to manually set a magical number every time.

Comment: `pgfgatt.sty` hardcoded several `\strut` in the value of various `xxx label text` keys. Removing them need patch internals of `pgfgatt.sty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `\strut` auto-inserted in bar label text, use

```
\ganttset{bar label text=#1}
```

To remove every `\strut` auto-inserted in similar areas, use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\ganttset{
  title label text=#1,
  bar label text=#1,
  group label text=#1,
  milestone label text=#1,
}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@newganttchartelement@definekeys
  {\strut}
  {}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[inline]{1}{4}
  \ganttbar{XX}{2}{3}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]